# Trigger click event to a list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `<li>` and I need trigger a click event over all them when the page is loaded. I have tried doing this with a loop but it's not working. Any help?

```
<ul>
    <li class="du">One</li>
    <li class="du">Two</li>
    <li class="du">Three</li>
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $('.du');
    for (i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
        $(list).click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to loop, just select all the `.du` elements and call `click()`. jQuery will raise the event on all matched elements in the set by itself:

```
$('.du').click();
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ougzt7ev/)

Also note that to loop over a set of elements selected with jQuery you should use the `each()` method, and refer to the element of the current iteration using the `this` keyword:

```
$('.du').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: A conflict in my code was causing the function not be loaded either . Now, it is all fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can simply do

```
$('.du').click(); // Will trigger click on all .du
```

In your code pick the element from list and click

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var list = $('.du');
    for(i=0;i<=list.length;i++){
      list.eq(i).click();
    }
});
```